# Expand group row programmatically in expandable list

Tags: android

I am using expandablelistview. Is there anyway I can expand the group row when an image inside is clicked? I know that to have the image respond to click, I have to set its focus. Now, once this image responds to click (inside my custome adapter), how can I programmatically expand/collapse that specific group row it belongs to?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In adapter

```
private OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedCallback;

public interface OnItemsSelectedListener {
    public void onImageSelected(int groupPos);
}

public YourAdapter(Context context) {
    try {
        this.onItemSelectedCallback = (OnItemSelectedListener ) context;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement OnItemSelectedListener ");
    }
}
```

Add this in getView()

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
imageView.setTag(R.id.tagGroupPosition, groupPosition);
imageView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Add this in OnClickListener

```
OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int groupPos = ((ImageView) v).getTagId(R.id.tagGroupPosition);
        onItemSelectedCallback.onImageSelected(groupPos);
    }
}
```

Then in activity you have to implements YourAdapter.OnItemsSelectedListener the Override onImageSelected

```
@Override
public void onImageSelected(int groupPos){
    if(expandableList.isGroupExpanded(groupPos)){
        expandableList.collapseGroup(groupPos);
    }else{
        expandableList.expandGroup(groupPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the collapse/expand answer which is the reason behind my question?

Comment: I have add more code to clarify my answer please see it. Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way:

1. Pass a reference to the `ExpandableListView` in the adapter constructor;
2. in `getGroupView` add an `OnClickListener` on the button you need and simply call `listView.expandGroup(position);`

Example:

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private ExpandableListView listView;

public ReportsAdapter(ExpandableListView listView) {
    this.listView = listView;
}

//...

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int position, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ParentViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.your_item, parent, false);

        holder = new ParentViewHolder();

        //... holder logic


        holder.btnExpand = convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_expand);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ParentViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //..holder logic

    holder.btnExpand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listView.expandGroup(position);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

In your Activity `onCreate()` or Fragment `onCreateView()` have

```
ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_list_view);
    mAdapter = new YourAdapter(listView);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: simple but bad practise. The cool idea behind adapters is that you don't really need to know where it's drawing, and shouldn't pass other ux references. In this way you risk to lose the reference of the listview and crashing the app

Answer (score 0):

This won't answer the question from OP, but I ended up here looking for a way to expand programmatically a group only after the adapter loaded the items, here my fix:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, viewModel);

adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
     @Override
     public void onChanged() {
          super.onChanged();
          if (adapter.getGroupCount()>0) {
               binding.expandableListView.expandGroup(0);
          }
        }
    });
binding.expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```