# Expand particular group in ExpandableListView programmatically

Tags: android, android-listview

[My question is not duplicate because I haven't used ImageView]
I tried with below method, but it expands all groups

```
 //method to expand all groups
    private void expandAll() {
        int count = expandableCategoryAdapter.getGroupCount().;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            expandableListView.expandGroup(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats because you does it for each group with this `for loop`. Just call `expandGroup` for one position which you need to expand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand group row programmatically in expandable list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879207/expand-group-row-programmatically-in-expandable-list)

Comment: @ADM My question is not duplicate because I haven't ImageView] I tried with below method, but it expands all groups

Comment: @yash786 true yash!

Comment: @yash786 yes right

Comment: @ADM Sure, buddy as a Indian i'm sincerely apologise for Arpi comments.And by the way ADM i just saw your profile we're working nearby in a same Country.

Comment: @yash786 it's okay

Comment: @ArpiSingh Is your issue solved.?

Comment: @yash786 yup dear

Comment: @ArpiSingh Is it possible to see your full code of that particular activity or fragments.?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are explicitly expanding all groups within **`ExpandableListView`** that's why all groups got expanded.

Don't use this:

```
 //method to expand all groups
private void expandAll() {
    int count = expandableCategoryAdapter.getGroupCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        expandableListView.expandGroup(i);
    }
}
```

Use this :

```
expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener((parent, v, groupPosition, id) -> {
                    expandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
                    return false;
});
```